# How to perform arithmentic operation in delayExpression in @Backoff (Spring-retry)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to take delay time in minutes from ENV variable. How to convert minutes into ms in expression string?

```
@Backoff(delayExpression = "${delay_in_minutes:2} * 60 * 1000",
         maxDelayExpression = "${max_delay_in_minutes:10} * 60 * 1000",
         multiplierExpression = "${multiplier:2.0}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SEPL(Spring expression language) like below:

```
@Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${delay_in_minutes:2} * 60 * 1000}",
         maxDelayExpression = "#{${max_delay_in_minutes:10} * 60 * 1000}",
         multiplierExpression = "${multiplier:2.0}")
```